# game center achievements unlock

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, gamekit, game-center

I want to add achievements to my app. I added a achievement in itunesconnect and found this method in the reference library:

```
-(void) reportAchievementIdentifier: (NSString*) identifier percentComplete: (float) percent {
GKAchievement *achievement = [[[GKAchievement alloc] initWithIdentifier: identifier] autorelease];
if (achievement)
{
    achievement.percentComplete = percent;
    [achievement reportAchievementWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error)
     {
         if (error != nil)
         {
             // Retain the achievement object and try again later (not shown).
         }
     }];
} }
```

so I added this to my app. now I want that the achievement is unlocked when an int has the value 5.
how could a method look like that unlocks this achievement when the int is 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it would be:

```
if(myInt >= 5)
{
[self reportAchievementIdentifier:@"myAchievement1" percentComplete:100];
}
```

Comment: you could also do: 'percentComplete:(100/myInt)' instead, so you don't have to check if it's bigger than 5.